# Error in Minimisation using the nlminb R-function

Tags: r

I would like to estimate the 4-parameters that minimises the log-likelihood function LogL(\theta). The first two parameters (a and sigma) are positive; the third one is unconstrained and the last one should be leas than the minimum value in the data. So, I tried to use nlminb function and write it as:

```
nlminb(start=c(a=0.13,mu=1,sigma=31,xi=0.01),f,lower=c(0.0001,0,0.123,0.01210),
upper=c(2,18.21,50,0.95),control=list(eval.max=100, iter.max=100))
```

I got a good result, but there is still problem that the estimator of mu take the same value of the upper limit for all the values I try to use and for xi, it take the same lower value even If I change the starting values.

The log likelihood function take form:

```
-loglik=-n*log(a)+n*log(1-exp(-1))+n*log(sigma) -(a-1)*sum(log(x-mu))+(1/xi+1)*sum(log(1+xi*((x-mu)**a)/sigma))+ sum((1+xi*((x-mu)**a)/sigma)*(-1/xi))
```

I have another condition that `x-mu` should be positive and `1+xi*((x-mu)*a)/sigma` as well

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: I tried to use optim and nlm, but they didn't work. Also, I can't get stable solution.

Comment: the log likelihood function take form:                              -loglik=-n*log(a)+n*log(1-exp(-1))+n*log(sigma)
-(a-1)*sum(log(x-mu))+(1/xi+1)*sum(log(1+xi*((x-mu)**a)/sigma))+
sum((1+xi*((x-mu)**a)/sigma)**(-1/xi)). So, I've another condition that x-mu should be positive and 1+xi*((x-mu)**a)/sigma as well.

Comment: Don't add comments to your own questions - just edit the question

Comment: http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html

Comment: You can see a worked example of a triangular constraint implemented here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436630/constrained-optimization-in-r/5438419#5438419 . I cannot tell whether `1+xi*((x-mu)*a)/sigma > 0` would be even a linear constraint, so you may need other methods, which was why I posted the link to the Task View first.

Comment: Minimizing against 4 parameters most likely means the function itself has a lot of local minima and saddlepoints.  By the way, what are `n` and `x` ?

Comment: n is the sample size and x is random variable. However, I am trying to find the values of the 4 parameters that minimize the -log-likelihood function. so, these values will be the MLEs