# Linear constraint in a function optimization in r

Tags: r, function, optimization, constraints

I have this function to maximize:

```
funcToOpt <- function (theta1,theta2,theta3)
{
  inner <- rowSums((wb + (theta1*X1+theta2*X2+theta3*X3) / Nt) * r)  
  innerU <- u(inner, gamma)                                     # u() is another function 

  return (sum(innerU) / T)
}

fbb <- function(x) funcToOpt(x[1],x[2],x[3])
max <- optim(c(0,0,0),fbb,control=list(fnscale=-1))
```

Where: `wb,X1,X2,X3,r` are `TxN` matrices and `Nt` a vector with length of `N`

I want that

```
(wb + (theta1*X1+theta2*X2+theta3*X3) / Nt)
```

... can't assume `negative` values.

Comment: Could you clarify your second to last sentence? I suspect you meant to put in another few words

Comment: @Dason: I'm puzzled that a duplicate with no upvoted answer was accepted by the system. I thought there needed to be an answer with a postive score.

Comment: @42- Well the linked question wasn't downvoted and it quite literally is an exact duplicate so I don't feel bad. Was I in the wrong here?

Comment: @Dason. I'm not sure you were "wrong". I'm just puzzled because my earlier efforts to label questions as "dupes" were system-blocked because an existen  answer (that I thought was correct) was not accepted or upvoted. In this case there wasn't either an upvoted answer or an upvote for the question.

Comment: (I would have closed as unclear because of the `u()` function that was not provided.)  And here is an answer to a quesiton involving inequality constraints: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436630/constrained-optimization-in-r

Comment: @42 In this case since neither question has visible answers it's fine.  I don't think you can close a question that has answers as a duplicate of a question that doesn't have answers.  Is that maybe what happened in your case?