# Minimise objective function using R

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

Can somebody help me in solving this to multivariate function parameters optimization in R, I have a data set like this. This is just a subset of data, dimension of the full dataset is `n type * m regions * 12 months`.

```
Month   region  type physics maths allsub 
Jan     r1       1      4     5      9        
Feb     r1       1      3     8      11      
Mar     r1       1      5     4      9
Apr     r1       1      6     7      13
May     r1       1      4     4      8
Jun     r1       1      8     9      17
Jul     r1       1      4     3      7
Aug     r1       1      5     4      9
Sep     r1       1      3     8      11
Oct     r1       1      9     2      11
Nov     r1       1      4     7      11
Dec     r1       1      7     3      10
Jan     r1       2      5     8      13
Feb     r1       2      4     9      13
Mar     r1       2      8     3      11
Apr     r1       2      5     6      11
May     r1       2      6     4      10
Jun     r1       2      7     6      13
Jul     r1       2      3     7      10
Aug     r1       2      4     8      12
Sep     r1       2      4     4      8
Oct     r1       2      8     1      9
Nov     r1       2      2     3      5
Dec     r1       2      1     6      7

...     ...        ..  ...    ...   ....
...     ...        ..  ...    ...   ....
```

I have one more dataset which has maximum number of physics and maths students in each region. And my objective function is this, `100*(physics) + 65*(maths) >= 0`. I want to minimize this function and my constraints are
 1. sum of physics and maths should always be equal to allsub for that region and month.
 2. total number of physics students in a region every month should be less than maximum number of physics students available in that region.
 3. total number of maths students in a region every month should be less than maximum number of maths students available in that region.

I am trying to use R. The whole idea is to find the right number of physics and maths students in each region/type/month minimizing the objective function and meeting the constraints. Can someone help me with this?

**EDIT** : As requested in the comments.
Here is the total capacity dataset. dataframe name = totalcap

```
   Month region physicscap mathscap
1    Jan   r1    9            13
2    Feb   r1    7            17
3    Mar   r1    13           7
4    Apr   r1    11           13
5    May   r1    10           8
6    Jun   r1    15           15
7    Jul   r1    7            10
8    Aug   r1    9            12
9    Sep   r1    7            12   
10   Oct   r1    17           3
11   Nov   r1    6            10
12   Dec   r1    8            9
```

Here is the script I have tried,

```
library(dplyr) 
library(MASS)
library(Rsolnp)

Month <- c('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec')
region <- c('r1')
physicscap <- c(5,5,8,6,7,9,5,6,4,10,5,8)
mathscap <- c(5,8,5,8,5,10,5,5,8,5,8,5)

totalcap <- data.frame(Month,region,physicscap,mathscap)
    #Constraints for the optimization.
constraints2 <- function(efforts){
  # constraints are:
  # 1. effort - allsub <= 0 in each region/month
  #     
  efforts$effort_calculated <- efforts$physics + efforts+maths
  reqeff <- summarise(group_by(efforts,region,Month),monthlyeffreg=sum(effort_calculated))
  reqeffallsub <- summarise(group_by(efforts,region,Month),allsubsum=sum(allsub))
  cons1 <- mutate(inner_join(reqeff,reqeffallsub,by=c('region'='region','Month'='Month'))
    ,diff=monthlyeffreg-allsubsum)
  constout <- cons1$diff


  # 2. sum(physics) - total physics available <= 0 in each region/month
  #
  phyreqeff <- summarise(group_by(efforts,region,Month),physicseff=sum(physics))
  cons2 <- mutate(inner_join(totalcap,phyreqeff,by=c('region'='region','Month'='Month')),
                   diff=physicseff-physicscap)
  constout <- c(constout,cons2$diff)


  # 3. sum(maths) - total maths available <= 0 in each region/month
  #
  matreqeff <- summarise(group_by(efforts,region,Month),mathseff=sum(maths))
  cons3 <- mutate(inner_join(totalcap,matreqeff,by=c('region'='region','Month'='Month')),
                   diff=mathseff-mathscap)
  constout <- c(constout,cons3$diff)
  constout
}


#Objective function to minimize the cost function.
objectivefunc <- function(efforts){
  nb_physics <- sum(efforts$physics)
  nb_maths <- sum(efforts$maths)
  objective <- (100*nb_physics + 55*nb_maths - 110)
  objective
}

Out2 <- solnp(pars = efforts,fun=objectivefunc,ineqfun=constraints2,ineqLB = rep(-100000,36), 
              ineqUB = rep(0,36), LB = rep(0,length(u)))
```

Here is the error I am getting,

```
Error in p0/vscale[(neq + 2):(nc + np + 1)] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Hope this clears the questions in comments. I tried my level best here, hope someone help me in solving this.

Comment: SO is not a package search and code writing service. You should have 1) searched for necessary R libraries, and 2) then posted all the R code that encoded the function, installed needed libraries, loaded them, and represented all the constraints.

Comment: This question appears to be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436630/constrained-optimization-in-r although I disagree that `100*(physics) + 65*(maths) >= 0` could be an objective function. It's a logical expression and could only take on one of two values.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. you are right, I have done my coding, written my constraints & objective function. when I try to run it using solnp package, I got this error. Error in p0/vscale[(neq + 2):(nc + np + 1)] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator. So I am trying to understand if I am doing something wrong and see if any other options to achieve the result. And what I have given here is just an example, so not to worry too much on the structure. thanks again.

Comment: @42- I have updated the question. Hope it answers all your question. Ask for any clarifications, I can update it further.

Comment: I tried, but I don't yet understand yours goals (as expressed in natural language and relating to a real world problem) and I cannot therefore specify where to modify your setup. In particular I don't understand what parameters are to be modified on the basis of evaluation of the objective function. I also do not see a creation of `u`. I've never used `Rsonlp` and thinking this was a problem involving inequality constraints was expecting to use `constrOptim`. So all the stuff setting up a function to handle constraints doesn't help me. It may be correct. I just don't know.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. Yes the constraints are set up as inequity constraints here. Then 'u' is my main dataset I mentioned in the very starting. May be I have set up this complex or wrong. The whole idea is that given the first dataset 'u' and second dataset 'totalcap' , I am trying to find the right number of physics and maths students in each region/month/type to minimise the objective function.

Comment: Need code that can be copied into a console session. Need to show how the `constraints2` function is being called.  I would have thought that the number of students in each region was a given, i.e. part of the data. What does the cost function actually represent?

Comment: First thing, yes you can use this code in your console. It has almost everything. Second thing, constraints2 function was called in solnp as 'ineqfun' if you read the solnp document. Then, number of students in each region was given in the second dataset called totalcap, though it's a subset of data, whole data looks same with some random numbers. Finally cost function is objective function I am trying to minimise that is (100*number of physics students selected + 55*number of maths students selected - 110) . Cost for physics students is 100, for maths students is 55 and 110 is the discount.

Comment: You should check your function code or the data setup.  I'm getting this error: `Error in inner_join(totalcap, phyreqeff, by = c(region = "region", Month = "Month")) : 
  object 'totalcap' not found`

Comment: Now I get an error: Error: 'region' column not found in lhs, cannot join. Please edit the code to reflect spelling

Comment: I can see the "region" columns in both dataset efforts & totalcap. Can you check again please?

Comment: SO would be a better place and you would have a better chance of getting an answer if you copied the work that is here, fixed all the errors and reposted it with a library call to load pkg:Rsolnp. I don't remember if Rsolnp still requires an external package but if so you should warn people and give them a link. I'm not the guy to debug this.

Comment: Is it possible that some constraints are missing? As far as I can see the solution (0, 0) fullfills all constraints and minimizes the objective.

Comment: You are right, that's my mistake. First constraint should be equal to allsub, just corrected it. Thanks

Comment: So do I understand you right that you do not want to use the columns "physics" and "maths" in your optimization procedure, but rather find values for these columns?

Comment: Yes exactly. That's what I am trying to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach with `lpSolveAPI`:

```
dat <- data.frame(
    mon=rep(c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"),2),
    region="r1", 
    type=c(rep("1", 12), rep("2", 12)),
    physicsmin=1,
    mathsmin=1,
    allsub=c(9, 11, 9, 13, 8, 17, 7, 9, 11, 11, 11, 10, 13,13,11,11,10,13,10,12,8,9,5,7),
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE
)
dat
capdat <- data.frame(
    mon=c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"),
    region="r1",
    physicscap=c(9,7,13,11,10,15,7,9,7,17,6,8),
    mathscap=c(13,17,7,13,8,15,10,12,12,3,10,9),
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE
)
capdat
```

Now for each month/region combination an optimization problem is to be solved. That is why
we wrap the calculation in a function:

```
library(lpSolveAPI)
ntypes <- length(unique(dat[,"type"])) # number of types
typemap <- setNames(seq.int(ntypes), unique(dat[,"type"])) # map typename to 1,...,ntypes

solve_one <- function(subdat, capdat) {

    # create object
    lprec <- make.lp(0, ncol=2*ntypes) # for each type, two decision variables

    # By convention, we assume that the first ntypes variables are physics for type 1, ..., ntypes
    # and the second ntypes variables are maths

    # add objective and type
    set.objfn(lprec, obj=c(rep(100, ntypes), rep(65, ntypes))) 
    set.type(lprec, columns=seq.int(2*ntypes), type="integer") # no reals

    # add capacity constraints
    idx <- which(capdat[,"mon"]==subdat[1,"mon"] & capdat[,"region"]==subdat[1,"region"]) # lookup the right cap
    add.constraint(lprec, rep(1, ntypes), type="<=", rhs=capdat[idx,"physicscap"], indices=seq.int(ntypes))
    add.constraint(lprec, rep(1, ntypes), type="<=", rhs=capdat[idx,"mathscap"], indices=seq.int(ntypes+1, 2*ntypes))

    # add allsub equality constraints and minimum constraints
    for (typ in subdat[,"type"]) {
        add.constraint(lprec, c(1,1), type="=", rhs=subdat[typemap[typ], "allsub"], indices=c(typemap[typ], ntypes+typemap[typ]))
        add.constraint(lprec, 1, type=">=", rhs=subdat[typemap[typ],"physicsmin"], indices=typemap[typ])
        add.constraint(lprec, 1, type=">=", rhs=subdat[typemap[typ],"mathsmin"], indices=ntypes+typemap[typ])
    }

    # solution data.frame
    ans <- subdat[, c("mon", "region", "type")]

    # solve       
    if(solve(lprec)==0) {
        sol <- get.variables(lprec)
        for (i in seq.int(nrow(subdat))) {
            ans[i, "physics"] <- sol[typemap[subdat[i,"type"]]]
            ans[i, "maths"] <- sol[typemap[subdat[i,"type"]]+ntypes]
        }
    } else ans[,c("physics", "maths")] <- NA # no solution found

    return(ans)
}
```

Now we apply the function to each subdataset which includes all types for each month/region combination. We
use a [split/apply/combine](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v040i01) approach here:

```
sp <- split(dat, list(dat[,"mon"], dat[,"region"]))
results <- lapply(sp, solve_one, capdat=capdat)
results <- do.call(rbind, results)
rownames(results) <- NULL
results
```

The code does not assume that for each month/region combination all types are present (some types may be omitted), however the solution will be wrong if there are several entries present for the same month/region/type combination. (the code would need to be adapted for this).

Comment: Did you consider that the physicscap and mathscap is region level, not each type level. So the constraints one and two is sum(physics) in a region should be less than physicscap in that region. Similarly for maths.

Comment: So the constraint is that for each month and region, the sum of the physics students over all types must be below the physicscap of that region/month? (and similarly for math)

Comment: Could you expand your example data so it includes two types? This would make it easier to check my answer.

Comment: Updated the data. Can you please check now?

Comment: Updated the answer, hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort. Let me check this.

Comment: I see in output,some rows has zero in it for either maths or physics. As per the model, its right, but ideally it has to select a minimum number in physics. let's say, we have a column which says minimum number of students to be selected in physics, how can i embed that? sorry, i never used lpsolveAPI before. Also, in the objective function, i have to substract 110 if you see my code above. you have not included it I guess.

Comment: I added some additional constraints for that. Also the dat data.frame has now two additional columns to set the minimums.

Comment: Constant terms have no impact on the decisions variables, that is, c1*physics+c2*math results in the same minimum as c1*physic+c2*math+c3

Comment: Oh yes. so I can add that calculation after finding the optimized values. Awesome, thanks a lot Karsten. you know what, you completely changed my day, tons and tons of thanks to you. I still have some more calculations to be done on this, i will try to add them and see if i understood it right. thank you very much.. :)

Comment: It was fun.. Have a nice day.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121034/discussion-between-ds-user-and-karsten-w).