# Struggling with simple constraints in constrOptim

Tags: r, optimization, constraints

I have a function in R that I wish to maximise subject to some simple constraints in `optim` or `constrOptim`, but I'm struggling to get my head around `ci` and `ui`to fit my constraints.

My function is:

```
negexpKPI <- function(alpha,beta,spend){

  -sum(alpha*(1-exp(-spend/beta)))

}
```

where `alpha` and `beta` are fixed vectors, and `spend` is a vector of spends `c(sp1,sp2,...,sp6)` which I want to vary in order to maximise the output of `negexpKPI`. I want to constrain `spend` in three different ways:

1) Min and max for each `sp1,sp2,...,sp6`, i.e

`0 < sp1 < 10000000`
`5000 < sp2 < 10000000`
...

2) A total sum:

`sum(spend)=90000000`

3) A sum for some individual components:

`sum(sp1,sp2)=5000000`

Any help please? Open to any other methods that would work but would prefer base R if possible.

Comment: All vectors are of length 6. I just want to change the components of the `spend` vector. So we have `alpha <- c(a1,a2,...,a6)`, `beta <- c(b1,b2,...,b6)` which are fixed, and I want to change `c(sp1,sp2,...,sp6)` to maximise the function.

Comment: Sorry, I was using sample data that I hadn't fully checked; the true optimisation is for 40 `sp` values with 92 constraints which would if I'd replicated here in full would have made the problem more difficult to explain. I've added a few extra zeroes to make it feasible now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to `?constrOptim`:

```
The feasible region is defined by ‘ui %*% theta - ci >= 0’. The
starting value must be in the interior of the feasible region, but
the minimum may be on the boundary.
```

So it is just a matter of rewriting your constraints in matrix format. Note, an identity constraint is just two inequality constraints.

[image]

Now we can define in R:

```
## define by column
ui = matrix(c(1,-1,0,0,1,-1,1,-1,
              0,0,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,
              0,0,0,0,0,0,1,-1,
              0,0,0,0,0,0,1,-1,
              0,0,0,0,0,0,1,-1,
              0,0,0,0,0,0,1,-1), ncol = 6)

ci = c(0, -1000000, 5000, -1000000, 5000000, 90000000, -90000000)
```

---

**Additional Note**

I think there is something wrong here. `sp1 + sp2 = 5000000`, but both `sp1` and `sp2` can not be greater than `1000000`. So there is no feasible region! Please fix your question first.

> Sorry, I was using sample data that I hadn't fully checked; the true optimisation is for 40 `sp` values with 92 constraints which would if I'd replicated here in full would have made the problem more difficult to explain. I've added a few extra zeroes to make it feasible now.

Comment: I was considering marking as duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436630/constrained-optimization-in-r/5438419#5438419, but I found the documentation of that function so confusing that I think having another good example on SO is a "good idea". Upvoted answer but not the question.

Comment: I thought your answer was complementary to mine. Your call but I suggest leaving it "un-duped" for at least day or two if I were you. Might get more attention which would be a "good thing". I like reading your answers. You've taught me a thing or two.

Comment: With no disrespect intended to @42's answer, I think this lays out really clearly the process for dealing with `ui` and `ci` in the most common types of constraint. By all means mark the question as dupe, but the answer is spectacularly clear and I suspect useful elsewhere. Thank you.