# Optimization with constraints R

Tags: r

I'm trying to solve the following optimization problem,
i want to minimize the distance (log(1+exp(x))-ax^2-bx-c)^2, in regards to some parameters a,b,c in an area around x, but also to satisfy the inequality log(1+exp(x))<=ax^2+bx+c for all x. Is there any solution to such problems?

Comment: This may help :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436630/constrained-optimization-in-r

Answer (score 1):

**1/ Case 1  ( `a , b , c`  are constants ) :**

```
library(nloptr)

fn <- function(x,a=1,b=1,c=1) { 
(log(1+exp(x))-a*x^2-b*x-c)^2
}

fn(1)

eval_g0 <-function( x, a=1,b=1,c=1 ) { return( log(1+exp(x))-a*x^2-b*x-c) }

eval_g0(0)
a=1
b=1
c=1
res1 <-nloptr(x0=c(10),eval_f=fn,lb =c(-Inf),ub =c(Inf),eval_g_ineq =eval_g0,opts =list("algorithm"="NLOPT_LN_COBYLA","xtol_rel"=1.0e-8),a =a,b =b ,c=c)

res1
```

This output the following :  .

```
[1] 2.845086
[1] -0.3068528

Call:

nloptr(x0 = c(10), eval_f = fn, lb = c(-Inf), ub = c(Inf), eval_g_ineq = eval_g0, 
    opts = list(algorithm = "NLOPT_LN_COBYLA", xtol_rel = 1e-08), 
    a = a, b = b, c = c)


Minimization using NLopt version 2.4.2 

NLopt solver status: 4 ( NLOPT_XTOL_REACHED: Optimization stopped because 
xtol_rel or xtol_abs (above) was reached. )

Number of Iterations....: 42 
Termination conditions:  xtol_rel: 1e-08 
Number of inequality constraints:  1 
Number of equality constraints:    0 
Optimal value of objective function:  0.0554408002852988 
Optimal value of controls: -0.2854395
```

To understand how things works , you could have a look at :

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nloptr/vignettes/nloptr.pdf

**2/ Case 2 `x, a, b , c` are variables :**

In the case where `a`,`b`,`c` are also variables , just use a vector `x` as entry :

```
library(nloptr)

fn <- function(x) { 
a=x[2]
b=x[3]
c=x[4]
return((log(1+exp(x[1]))-a*(x[1])^2-b*(x[1])-c)^2)
}



eval_g0 <-function(x) { 
a=x[2]
b=x[3]
c=x[4]
return((log(1+exp(x[1]))-a*(x[1])^2-b*(x[1])-c)^2) }


res1 <-nloptr(x0=rep(18,4),eval_f=fn,lb =rep(-Inf,4),ub =rep(Inf,4),eval_g_ineq =eval_g0,opts =list("algorithm"="NLOPT_LN_COBYLA","xtol_rel"=1.0e-8))

res1
```

Here you could notify that `x[1]` ( which is the first element of the vector `x` ) is simply your main function variable `x` of `f(x,a,b,c)` of `4 variables`. This output the following :

```
Number of Iterations....: 100 
Termination conditions:  xtol_rel: 1e-08 
Number of inequality constraints:  1 
Number of equality constraints:    0 
Current value of objective function:  2.47413071040375e-09 
Current value of controls: -1.977346 6.058104 19.29975 14.60534
```

The solution of the pb is : `x=-1.977346, a=6.058104 , b=19.29975 , c=14.60534`

Let's verify the constraint `g`:

```
print(c("the constraint value for x is : "))
eval_g0(c(x=-1.977346, a=6.058104 , b=19.29975 , c=14.60534))

[1] "the constraint value for x is : "
           x 
1.232363e-09
```

Here normally , we should expect a negative number of the constraint value instead of a very small number that is near `0`. However, as explained in [nloptr documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nloptr/vignettes/nloptr.pdf) page 12 :

*" A **point x is considered feasible** for judging whether to stop the optimization **if eval_g_ineq(x) <= tol.** "*

In our case , we have `eval_g_ineq(x)= 1.232363e-09  <= tol=1e-08`. This means that things were going properly and we are ( numerically speaking ) within the feaseability domain .

**3/ Another constrained optimization problem :**

We will solve another constrained problem. Minimize `$ f= x^2 $`  under `$ 1-x <= 0 $`. The constraint is equivalent to `$ 1 <= x $` and the objective function is increasing in `[1, + inf [` . We will simply have `x*=1` as an optimum for the constrained problem. Let's do a check :

```
library(nloptr)

fn <- function(x) { 

return(x^2)

}



eval_g0 <-function(x) { 

return(1-x)

}


res1 <-nloptr(x0=rep(14),eval_f=fn,eval_g_ineq =eval_g0,opts =list("algorithm"="NLOPT_LN_COBYLA","xtol_rel"=1.0e-8))

res1

print(c("the constraint value for x is : "))

eval_g0(0.999999902845997)
```

This gives the following :

```
Call:

nloptr(x0 = rep(14), eval_f = fn, eval_g_ineq = eval_g0, opts = list(algorithm = "NLOPT_LN_COBYLA", 
    xtol_rel = 1e-08))


Minimization using NLopt version 2.4.2 

NLopt solver status: 4 ( NLOPT_XTOL_REACHED: Optimization stopped because 
xtol_rel or xtol_abs (above) was reached. )

Number of Iterations....: 18 
Termination conditions:  xtol_rel: 1e-08 
Number of inequality constraints:  1 
Number of equality constraints:    0 
Optimal value of objective function:  0.999999902845997 
Optimal value of controls: 1


[1] "the constraint value for x is : "
[1] 9.7154e-08
```

Comment: Note that you should specify your desired values of `a , b , c`. This function doesn't"t require the computation of the jacobian as it needs some efforts !

Comment: thank you for your reply! If I understand correctly, I should specify the values of a,b,c? I would like to find the optimal ones..

Comment: @meme , you just need to use a vector `x` of length=4 ( which is the number of variables ). Plz , click In the tick mark to accept the answer !

Comment: I updated the post to deal with the case where `a,b,c` are also variables and not constants !

Comment: Thank you very much, however I need the solution to satisfy the constraint not for the particular x but for all x. Maybe that's not feasible

Comment: @meme , it's a feasible solution and i already explained that ! You're searching an optimum under some constraint and this is what the proposed R code actually do !