# R function constrOptim can't return hessian matrix

Tags: r, math, optimization, mathematical-optimization

While I try to return hessian metrix and use the method "BFGS", error will come out. the code and errors are in below.

```
square <- function (par, y){
    return(- sum(dnorm(y, mean = par[1], sd = par[2], log = TRUE)))
}

ui <- c(1, -1)
ci <- c(0)
d.y <- rnorm(1000, 10, 6)
res <- constrOptim(theta = c(15, 5),square, grad = NULL, ui = ui, ci = ci, method = "BFGS", hessian = T, y = d.y)
```

error

```
Error in colSums(ui * gi.old/gi - ui) (constrOPtim.R#18): 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
```

I don't know if "BFGS" method needs more conditions. How can the program return the hessian matrix rightly whiling using "BFGS" method?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436630/constrained-optimization-in-r/5438419#5438419 (So ci might not need to be a matrix but ui probably does. Not sure if the choice of "BFGS" makes a difference. I think it might because if I make ui a matrix I get an error demanding that a gradiaent function be avaialble.

Comment: R runs without error if you `rbind` the ui values and use `res <- constrOptim(theta = c(15, 5),square, grad = NULL, ui = ui, ci = ci,  y = d.y)`

Comment: That's sure that if I turn `ui ` to a matrix and run `res <- constrOptim(theta = c(15, 5),square, grad = NULL, ui = ui, ci = ci,  y = d.y)`. The key point is that I do want to get a hessian matrix, when I run `res <- constrOptim(theta = c(15, 5),square, grad = NULL, ui = ui, ci = ci, hessian = T)`, the error is `Error in grad(theta, ...) (constrOPtim.R#17): could not find function "grad"`, why would this happen?